# xAxis last tick missing when offsetGridLines is set to 1 in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Im Trying to create a chart with xAxis shown like below using Chartjs

[image: required]
but increasing the offset for gridlines on xAxis with `offsetGridLines:1`,the last tick mark gets out
[image: obtained]
is there any way to configure Chartjs in correct way to get it

Here is a [flddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pratheeswaran/1wdqjLkj/15/) of the problem